# Moving an often used function to a class and calling from HTML code

Tags: c#, html, class, methods

I have a function written in C# that resides on 12 individual pages of an ASPX application.  I already use cs files in App_Code, so that is not the problem.

Here is the call in HTML:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat ="server" ImageUrl='<%# (string) FormatImageUrl( (string) Eval("Image")) %>' />
```

and here is the method:

```
protected string FormatImageUrl(string url)
{
if (url != null && url.Length > 0)
    return ("~/" + url);
else return null;
}
```

(A great find might I add.)

I want to move this method to App_Code and reference one instance from many pages.

I have looked into adding the namespace.function.method in the HTML code, but that throws an error.

I have also looked into using a DLL for the method, but I still can not 
reference it correctly in the HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time in think tank mode over the past couple of days and finally came up with the solution.

I created an App_Code class file named ImageFormatter.cs and it looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ImageFormatter
/// </summary>
public class ImageFormatter
{
    public ImageFormatter()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public static string FormatImageUrl(string url)
    {
    if (url != null && url.Length > 0)
    return ("~/" + url);
    else return null;
}
}
```

NOTE:  I removed the NameSpace definitioin and the associated { and }.

I commented out the FormatImageUrl function in two pages of the app to test my theory.

I modified the HTML code to look like this in the same two files.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat ="server" ImageUrl='<%# (string) ImageFormatter.FormatImageUrl( (string) Eval("Image")) %>' />
```

So for those of you needing to move a function to a class:

- create a class of appropriate name

  - place your function within the class (as I demonstrated)
  - Check for and remove NameSpace
- make sure to comment out the function in your code page
- modify the HTML code to include the Class Name